# Selenium Grid. Why HUB wrote "false" after registration Selenium RC?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Steps:
1. Run hub ("ant launch-hub")
2. Run registration of RC ("ant -Dport=5557 launch-remote-control")
3. Chek console of hub

Question:
In the console says: - RemoteControlProxy localhost:5557#false.
why does it say "false". I dont understand it.![alt text][1] 
But Selenium RC displayed in the browser in "Available Remote Controls" place.

Unfortunately, I cant post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question. 
False - it is correct message.